# Recursion with or cases

Tags: prolog

I am very new to prolog and I wanted to write a program that will either increase or decrease a number by 1 and then do the same to the result three times. The result I expected was a series of three numbers that represent all the ways this could turn out. For example if I give it the number 4, I could get,

567
565
545
543
456
454
434
432

correction 
567
565
545
543
345
343
323
321

I thought it would make sense to some combination or recursion and the or condition.

```
aos(_,3):- write('end').
aos(J,X):- (N is J+1, write(N),Y is X+1,aos(N,Y)); 
           (N is J-1, write(N), Y is X+1,aos(N,Y)).
```

The above is in my database file and below is the query I ran.

```
aos(4,0).
```

The output I would get is

`567end` and then when I hit next, it would proceed to output `89101112...`

I do not understand why this is happening and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you ask for the next solution, X gets increased to 4. The recursion continues, but because X is now above 3 your terminal case will never match.

You can see for yourself like so:

```
?- spy(aos/2).
% Spy point on aos/2
true.

[debug]  ?- aos(4,0).
 * Call: (8) aos(4, 0) ? Options:
+:                  spy        -:              no spy
/c|e|r|f|u|a goal:  find       .:              repeat find
a:                  abort      A:              alternatives
b:                  break      c (ret, space): creep
[depth] d:          depth      e:              exit
f:                  fail       [ndepth] g:     goals (backtrace)
h (?):              help       i:              ignore
l:                  leap       L:              listing
n:                  no debug   p:              print
r:                  retry      s:              skip
u:                  up         w:              write
m:                  exception details
C:                  toggle show context
 * Call: (8) aos(4, 0) ? creep
   Call: (9) _850 is 4+1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 5 is 4+1 ? creep
   Call: (9) write(5) ? creep
5
   Exit: (9) write(5) ? creep
   Call: (9) _856 is 0+1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 1 is 0+1 ? creep
 * Call: (9) aos(5, 1) ? creep
   Call: (10) _862 is 5+1 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 6 is 5+1 ? creep
   Call: (10) write(6) ? creep
6
   Exit: (10) write(6) ? creep
   Call: (10) _868 is 1+1 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 2 is 1+1 ? creep
 * Call: (10) aos(6, 2) ? creep
   Call: (11) _874 is 6+1 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 7 is 6+1 ? creep
   Call: (11) write(7) ? creep
7
   Exit: (11) write(7) ? creep
   Call: (11) _880 is 2+1 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 3 is 2+1 ? creep
 * Call: (11) aos(7, 3) ? creep
   Call: (12) write(end) ? creep
end
   Exit: (12) write(end) ? creep
 * Exit: (11) aos(7, 3) ? creep
 * Exit: (10) aos(6, 2) ? creep
 * Exit: (9) aos(5, 1) ? creep
 * Exit: (8) aos(4, 0) ? Unknown option (h for help)
 * Exit: (8) aos(4, 0) ? creep
true ;
 * Redo: (11) aos(7, 3) ? creep
   Call: (12) _886 is 7+1 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 8 is 7+1 ? creep
   Call: (12) write(8) ? creep
8
   Exit: (12) write(8) ? creep
   Call: (12) _892 is 3+1 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 4 is 3+1 ? creep
 * Call: (12) aos(8, 4) ? creep
   Call: (13) _898 is 8+1 ? creep
   Exit: (13) 9 is 8+1 ? creep
   Call: (13) write(9) ? creep
9
```

The problem is that when you ask for another solution, Prolog's last choice point was the innermost one after aos(7,3). So it will then enter the second branch with J=7 and X=3. You can address this problem like so:

```
aos(_,3):- write('end').
aos(J,X):- X < 3, ((N is J+1, write(N),Y is X+1,aos(N,Y)); 
                   (N is J-1, write(N), Y is X+1,aos(N,Y))).
```

However, this doesn't produce the output sequence you want. You get 567 5 45 3 345 3 23 1. I'm not entirely sure what you need to do to get that output sequence, but I suspect you need to group together your three additions and spreading them out using your second variable here is causing you trouble. I would probably implement like so:

```
inc_or_dec(X, Y) :- succ(X, Y).
inc_or_dec(X, Y) :- succ(Y, X).

aos(N) :- 
    inc_or_dec(N , N1), 
    inc_or_dec(N1, N2), 
    inc_or_dec(N2, N3), 
    write(N1), write(N2), write(N3), write('end'), nl.
```

This makes it more obvious to Prolog where the real choice points are, which is to say, not between individual digits in the groups of three. However, this still doesn't quite get you the sequence you want; you get 567 565 545 543 345 343 323 321. If you want to get solutions with 4 initially, you are going to have to relax a constraint and allow X to appear unchanged, but if you do that you will also get sequences like 444 and 555. It might be helpful to know what it is you're trying to achieve, rather than just how you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: I had made a mistake in my question, and your last solution is actually what I am trying to get. Thank you very much for your answer, you actually helped me understand other problems I was having.

Comment: @njemal no problem, glad to help. Please accept my answer if it was helpful to you